# Unable to install ltrace on Kali

Tags: linux

I am kind of stuck with the installation of `ltrace` on my Kali VM.

My `/etc/apt/sources.list` file is updated with following entry:

`deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib`

I am trying to install `ltrace` via `apt-get install ltrace`.
However, getting an error stating 
`unable to locate package ltrace`.

Could anyone help me out here?

---

Edit: It got resolved. Thank you all.

Comment: Since this is not an RE question on its own, try asking on Superuser, Unix&Linux, or Security instead. Or just check Kali's own support resources.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks about problems with a particular - not easy to wield - Linux distro. Even on unix.SE such a question [won't be well received](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/399626/5462), because of how many questions lack a basic understanding of Debian package management  in general and Kali-specifics.

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky I would try searching on Superuser or Unix&Linux. Thanks for the input.

Comment: @0xC0000022L I believe it is a forum to ask queries and resolve those. If I would have been clear, I would not have asked my query. Anyway, Stack is a place where people are of varied views and could help people like us to find a way. Nevertheless, Thanks for your input, appreciate it.

Comment: Ltrace is definitely there. See https://http.kali.org/pool/main/l/ltrace/ . When you say "updated", you mean you've run "sudo apt-get update" or the equivalent, right?

Comment: @dingo_kinznerhook yes I did `sudo apt-get update` and post that `sudo apt-get upgrade`. Should I edit my sources.list file and include the URL you mentioned?

Comment: Hey, it got resolved. I was able to install ltrace. Thanks all.

Comment: How do I close this question now ?

Comment: @JigerJain: for most practical purposes you'll want `apt-get dist-upgrade` _in place of_ `apt-get upgrade`. I know that the name of these commands is slightly misleading, so `dist-upgrade` will _not_ upgrade from disto version x to x+1 or so. But the package selection criteria differ. However, once you _know_ exactly what you're trying to achieve, you can mix and match these commands as needed.